# Should I accept the only answer in this instance even if it not definitive?

Tags: discussion, answers

I was going back over my older questions and noticed one where I had not chosen an answer. Normally I pick the best or most up-voted but this time there was only one answer.

[Add h-card or vcard to contacts (Ideally with Javascript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25736326/add-h-card-or-vcard-to-contacts-ideally-with-javascript)

In this case I suspect that the true answer might be "No, there isn't but there should be".

Should I accept the only answer or wait for a definitive "no" (or, optimistically, yes)?

Comment: Maybe the answer on this question answers your question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234 (<- See: *Which answer should I choose?*)

Comment: Well, I can't tell finally. Did it help you to find a solution for your problem? For me both the question and the answer don't look appropriate for SO. The question appears too broad, and the answer is more or less link only.

Comment: Not really. It helped me realize that the solution doesn't exist and might be VERY hard to implement. Now that you point it out it does not seem like a great fit for SO. Should I maybe think about getting it relocated?

Comment: IMO, you should think about improving your question : it is too broad/unclear and that's why you didn't receive any satisfactory answers. (think about the concept of "address book" : what is it precisely? there are thousands of "address book" on the market)

Comment: I would personally not check an answer that didn't answer my question or help me solve the problem. Consider [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23271079/dynamically-styling-a-non-inline-svg-with-css-or-javascript) where the answer is basically *can't be done*. I think it's perfectly fine to not accept an answer, just because something might not be possible **today** doesn't mean it never will be. Who knows, maybe someone comes breezing by in a year and makes you aware that it's suddenly possible? The web isn't static, standards are constantly improved and new APIs emerge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for me I don't choose the best or most up-voted answers , after all it's my question , what is the point if every body thought that is the answer , but I didn't get convinced about the answer ? 
so it's better to wait and not to choose an answer until totally convince answer comes , rather than you pic an answer that doesn't satisfies your question.